# Using min() on both Python2.4 and 2.6

Tags: python, min, argparse

I am attempting to use min() with argparse on both Python2.4 and 2.6.  I have the following code which works fine in 2.6 but in 2.4 is gives me a syntax error.  I have looked through the docs for 2.4 to try and figure this out and for some examples using 2.4 but have been unable to find any.  Argparse works fine in 2.4, from what I can tell.

line in argparse:

```
parser.add_argument("--no-alert-on-critical", action='store_true', help='disable critical alerts and dashboard status\'s for this check (default: yes)')
```

setting the variable:

```
critical_status_exit_code = min(1 if args.no_alert_on_critical else 2,
                                0 if args.no_alert_on_warning and args.no_alert_on_critical else 2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the trace of the Exception? It'd probably help narrow the issue? (maybe?)... dunno...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just skip using min()...

```
def calc_code():
    # pick a better function name
    if args.no_alert_on_critical:
        if args.no_alert_on_warning:
            return 0
        return 1
     return 2

critical_status_exit_code = calc_code()
```

Or...

```
critical_status_exit_code = 2
if args.no_alert_on_critical:
    critical_status_exit_code -= 1
    if args.no_alert_on_warning:
        critical_status_exit_code -= 1
```

Comment: Your first answer would be best as I am doing this on multiple files but I don't want to create multiple functions for each exit status(critical, unknown, warning)  You second answer is what I am implementing, it is the simplest and most easy to read.

Comment: If you're reusing in places, you can always use a function and pass in the status codes, if they are different. Also, it may be more readable in the second example to use 1 and 0, rather than -= 1 for each. I agree that Alex provides the actual reason for the issue, but it is sometimes good to look at the overall goal, as there are sometimes simpler solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operators were only added in Python 2.5, so any version before that will throw a `SyntaxError` in response to one. You'll have to define the variables the long way, with `if` and `else` statements:

```
if args.no_alert_on_critical:
    var = 1
else:
    var = 0
```

Do that with all of your values, then pass the variables in which they are stored to `min()`.

Comment: I am accepting another answer because it is simpler but I am still upvoting yours because you explained why my code didn't work which is just as important to me.